# How to detect my environment in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I am trying to deploy my app online and therefore I need to use different files depending on the environment. However, I don't know how to detect which environment I am working in.

Basically I am just looking for a variable which enables me to say if I am in development or in production to specify my static routes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Well this isn't a complete answer, but `process.env` is the Node.js portal to the environment variables used to start the app.
So, if you had your environment set via the `NODE_ENV` variable (which is a pseudo-standard for Node), you could do the following:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  doProductionThings();
} else {
  doDevelopmentThings();
}
```